# How to add error message for pre-filled input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a text-area  to display address from a string as an pre-filled input field.

**HTML**

```
  <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="businessaddress"  value="{{address}}"></textarea>
             <mat-error *ngIf="businessForm.controls.businessaddress.hasError('required')">
                 Please enter business address
              </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
 address = `#91,MG Road,Banglore`;
```

I am validating the text-area and displaying the error message using mat-error as shown in **HTML**

```
  businessaddress: [null, [Validators.required]],
```

Now its showing error message if i enter the input field(text-area) and leave.But i want it show error message if delete the input field content i,e(pre-filled data **value="{{address}}"**) then only it as to show error message.how to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of adding the value attribute to the textarea, add the value of the address to the formControl:

`businessaddress: [address, [Validators.required]],`

this should do the trick for you, because if you set value-attribute, it does not mean that the value is set in the formControl

edit: in your case you just set the `value` attribute of the input field, but the form and the field are not connected, you can do this either with template-forms, or you tried the reactive-form approach. for more detail I can recommend this blog post:
https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to set control value like `value="{{address}}`:

Initialize control value as:

```
businessaddress: this.formBuilder.control(address, [Validators.required]),
```

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="businessaddress"></textarea>
       <mat-error *ngIf="businessForm.controls.businessaddress.hasError('required') && businessForm.controls.businessaddress.touched">
                 Please enter business address
       </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you.